# Is there a way to force Varnish to read the Cache-Control header on 403 responses?

Tags: varnish, http-status-code-403, cache-control, varnish-vcl, varnish-4

It looks like from the code, that since a 403 is not a whitelisted status, the `Cache-Control` header is ignored:

```
switch (http_GetStatus(hp)) {
    default:
        expp->ttl = -1.;
```

https://github.com/varnishcache/varnish-cache/blob/4.0/bin/varnishd/cache/cache_rfc2616.c#L112-L114

This is the best I could come up with:

```
sub vcl_backend_response {
  if (beresp.status == 403) {
    set beresp.http.X-Status = beresp.status;
    set beresp.status = 200;
  }
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    if (resp.http.X-Status) {
      set resp.status = std.integer(resp.http.X-Status, 403);
      unset resp.http.X-Status;
    }
}
```

While this properly sets and unsets the status, every request is a cache `MISS`.

See [#2018](https://github.com/varnishcache/varnish-cache/issues/2018)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 403 response is not cached by default in varnish.

"You can cache other status codes than the ones listed above, but you have to set the beresp.ttl to a positive value in vcl_backend_response. "

See http://book.varnish-software.com/4.0/chapters/VCL_Basics.html#the-initial-value-of-beresp-ttl